# WSO2 Mashup using external services with arguments

Tags: javascript, web-services, wso2, mashup

I'm trying to create a mashup in WSO2 AS 5.1.0. I have managed to succesfully create a simple HelloWorld service, however when I try to integrate other service into it, I get an error.

This is my HelloWorld service:

```
this.documentation = "This is a test Hello World service";
system.include("HelloStub.js");

hello.documentation = "say hello"
hello.inputTypes = {"user": "string"}
hello.outputType = "string";
function hello(user){
    try{
        var response = services["admin/testmashup"].operations["sayMyName"](user);
    }catch(e){
        return "Danger, Robinson! " + e.toString()
    }
    return "Hello, there! " + response;
}

function whoAreYou(){
    try{
        var response = services["admin/testmashup"].operations["toString"]();
    }catch(e){
        return "Danger, Robinson! " + e.toString()
    }
    return "Hello! " + response;    
}
```

And this is the `admin/testmashup` service

```
this.serviceName = "testmashup";
this.documentation = "Test mashup service" ;

toString.documentation = "say something" ;
toString.inputTypes = { /* no arguments */ };
toString.outputType = "string"; 
function toString()
{
   return "Hi, my name is testmashup";
}

sayMyName.documentation = "Make me feel happy";
sayMyName.inputTypes = {"myName":"string"};
sayMyName.outputType = "string";
function sayMyName(myName){
    return "Your very beautiful name is " + myName;
}
```

I must note that when I call the `admin/testmashup` service, it works as expected.

The file `HelloStub.js` is a Javascript (E4X) stub, generated by the WSO2 Applicanton Server.

When I test the operation `whoAreYou`, which has no arguments, I get the following response:

```
<ws:whoAreYouResponse xmlns:ws="http://services.mashup.wso2.org/helloWorld?xsd">
   <return xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:js="http://www.wso2.org/ns/jstype" js:type="string" xsi:type="xs:string">Hello! &lt;ws:toStringResponse xmlns:ws="http://services.mashup.wso2.org/testmashup?xsd"&gt;&lt;return&gt;Hi, my name is testmashup&lt;/return&gt;&lt;/ws:toStringResponse&gt;</return>
</ws:whoAreYouResponse>
```

I can see the text `Hi, my name is testmashup` within the encoded response. But when I try to call `hello`, with the following xml:

```
<body>
   <p:hello xmlns:p="http://services.mashup.wso2.org/helloWorld?xsd">
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <user>John</user>
   </p:hello>
</body>
```

I get the following error:

```
<ws:helloResponse xmlns:ws="http://services.mashup.wso2.org/helloWorld?xsd">
   <return>Danger, Robinson! org.wso2.carbon.CarbonException: Invalid input for the payload in WSRequest Hostobject : John</return>
</ws:helloResponse>
```

I have tried to make this work for the last couple of days and have searched all over the place for an answer, but I can't seem to find it. The [official documentation](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AS510/Consuming+Services+Using+Stubs) does not provide an example using stubs of external webservices that have operations with one or more arguments.

Also, if it is possible, I would like to know how to consume REST-JSON services from a javascript mashup.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is an important bunch of information missing in the official documentation. In particular, regading my issue, it is important to know that internally the generated stub uses BagderFish notation to perform the conversion between XML and JSON. I went into the stub and dived a bit and foud this piece of code, concerning to my `sayMyName` method:

```
service.operations['sayMyName'] = function (request) {
    var isAsync, response, resultValue;
    var operation = service.operations['sayMyName'];
    request = typeof request === "string" ? request : utils.bf2xml(request);
    service.$._options = new Array();
    .
    .
    .
```

The function `bf2xml` converts JSON in BadgerFish notation to XML. The function is defined later in the stub, and can be found [here](http://ruchirawageesha.blogspot.com/2011/06/xml-to-json-and-json-to-xml-conversion.html) too. Information on BadgerFish notation is widely available also.

In order to make the `HelloWorld` service work properly, you can pass either a string with the XML (in that case the `bf2xml` function will not be called), or a JSON object with the correct notation, i.e, BadgerFish.

This will work:

```
var response = services["admin/testmashup"].operations["sayMyName"]({request : {myName:{$:user}}});
```

Comment: And it is the second time I answer my own question... would not be strange at all if it were not the second question I post, too...